# C# Постоянное увеличение потребления памяти и ЦП Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, chromedriver

Использую библиотеку Selenium c ChromeDriver. При длительном выполнении однотипных действий 
[image: Действия в тесте]

Google Chrome под управлением Chromedriver очень сильно начинает кушать память (за стуки теста под 2 гб. и почти весь ЦП). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде использую следующие опции инициализации хром драйвера

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("window-size=1800x1080");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArguments("--headless");
        var dir_chrome_driver = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\lib";
        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir_chrome_driver);
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        try  { web = new ChromeDriver(service,options); } catch (Exception e) {MessageBox.Show("Убедитесь в наличии браузера Google Chrome версии 72.0 и выше \nОшибка инициализации браузера, доступ запрещен или объект отстуствует. \n" + e.Message, "Error, Google Chrome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);  }                                                
        web.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Помогите! В чём может быть дело?

UPD Проблема не решена, но вот ещё пару мыслей

Есть подозрения, что это сам хром именно так работает, что частично подтверждается как из англ. язычных источников так и практических наблюдений. На мой взгляд всё дело в том, что хром хранит в памяти все модальные окна сеанса, для того что  бы можно было быстро переходить по ним в обратном направлении без загрузки. 
1) [модальное окно](https://d.radikal.ru/d41/1903/a9/1d5819da0710.png) 
2) [загрузка модального окна](https://b.radikal.ru/b05/1903/70/dc5cda31c59f.png)  Т.е. получается, чем больше нажимаешь стрелку вправо, тем больше хром начинает потреблять памяти и цп, т.к. хранит всё предыдущие модальные окна в памяти при чём без каких либо ограничений, но зато - да, открывает предыдущие окна (стрелочка влево) мгновенно без загрузки с ресурса, а сразу с памяти.

Нагрузка на память и ЦП мало заметна при 10-50 переходах, но когда цикл из 1к+ итераций, тогда использование объёма памяти становится где-то в районе 1гб+.

Можете сами проверить:

```
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/IT);
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).Click(); // открыть модальное окно. Самая первая запись в теге
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //кнопка стрелочка. следующий пост
}
```

P.S. Это мои субъективные домыслы, граничащие с интуицией. 
Очень бы хотелось услышать мнения гуру на этот счёт)

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что подбор параметров хрома может вообще решить эту проблему?  Может ваша страничка, что вы открываете, майнит биткойны или ещё что делает нехорошее, нагружая ваше железо.

Comment: О нет, это не какой нибудь левый адульт ресурс с майнерами :D:D:D Это вполне себе обычный Инстаграм. =)

Comment: Прошло около часа времени с момента скрина диспетчера задач, потребление памяти обоих процессов выросло на 200 мб. в среднем. Интересно, что будет когда потребление памяти вырастет до физического объёма ОЗУ?

Comment: _Интересно, что будет когда потребление памяти вырастет до физического объёма ОЗУ?_ - сработает сборщик мусора (garbage collector) и освободит занятую память.

Comment: В современных системах памяти много. Современные программные платформы, будь то .NET, Java, Python и другие, разменивают память на скорость. Выделение памяти в таких платформах очень дёшево, а очистка - дорога. Поэтому, пока в системе память есть, они её потребляют, но не освобождают. А вот когда памяти станет мало, включается сборщик мусора и освобождает память. Так что относительно большое потребление памяти - это нормально. Ненормально, если эта память не освобождается даже когда в этом возникает потребность.

Comment: Не думаю, что это правильный подход брать неограниченный объём памяти со стороны Google Chrome, тем самым приводя компьютер пользователя к диким тормозам. UPD вопроса.

Comment: Нажми в хроме Shift+Esc и рассмотри таск менеджер хрома. Может там будет какая информация полезная. Так же нужно было бы перечислить все экстеншны установленные на хром и сколько вкладок открыто в принципе. Возможно будет полезной статья https://lifehacker.com/why-chrome-uses-so-much-freaking-ram-1702537477

Comment: открыто вкладок 1, расширений 0 т.к. по умолчанию Selenium запускает чистый хром.

Comment: репродьюсится ли даное поведение БЕЗ селениума? Может это проблема драйвера.

Comment: Чёрт возьми - да! Хах, всё дело в самом движке хрома, как я и думал) Вручную походил по модальным окнам https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/IT примерно за одно нажатие на кнопку (стрелочка вправо) объём задествованной хромом памяти увеличивается в среднем на 1 мб. Проверьте у себя. Эх, раньше считал хром самым оптимизированным браузером, но оказалось это не так.

Comment: Он не только не самый оптимизированный, а и совсем небезопасный за счет неотключаемого WebRTC. Самым оптимизированным является Safari. На маке точно. Низкое потребление памяти, низкое потребление проца и низкое потребление батареи ноута. У хрома и у фаярфокса значительно выше прожорливость во всем. Но лично я маком не пользуюсь и сижу на лисе.

Comment: _считал хром самым оптимизированным браузером_ - спасибо, смеялся :Р